# MailCore2 Alternative

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mailcore2

I've spent a great deal of time creating an Objective-C based application for the iPhone.  I incorporated MailCore2 so that emails could be sent without a dialog popping up (Apple's system of in-app email).  My app works perfectly on all of my devices, including all outside devices associated with TestFlight beta testing.  Unfortunately, the moment Apple reviews the app, they always reject it, saying that MailCore2 made an AlertView with the contents: "Error! Please connect to the internet or try again later.", and the email never properly sends.

My question is, is there an alternative to MailCore2?  I've heard of MailGun, but I see no documentation on their site for either Objective-C or Swift.

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like this issue is unrelated to mailcore and you need to discuss properly with the review team or show a good error message. Disclosure: I'm the main author of mailcore2.

Answer (score 0):

Mailigun is a services and yes you can send mail with Mailgun, but not receive mail like normal email app. Anyway it is completely different from mailcore (Imap/pop). Mailcore is so hard to use...
 If you need only send email i can provide you entirely code for achieve this using mailgun.

Comment: That would be great! I am only sending email in my app. I don't need to receive it. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088315/how-to-send-multiple-file-as-attachment-in-multipart-forms-http-post-request/31088527#31088527

Comment: for any question i am here... hope help

Comment: Hi. I recently posted another question regarding the MailCore2 API. Since you seem very knowledgeable in this area, would you be able to take a look? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909821/email-account-for-mailcore2